# Template and struct for 2d array 

Tags: c++, templates, static, struct, constants

I'm trying to make a *2d array struct container* with template and struct, heres my code:

```
// T = 2darray type; LIN = lines count; COL = cols count
template <class T, int LIN, int COL>
struct Matrix {
    T val[LIN][COL];
    static const int linCount = LIN;
    static const int colCount = COL;
    static const int size = LIN*COL;
};
```

my compiler said to me to put the 'static const' in the struct members, it works, but as being static members, will they be shared to all struct instances I create?

- If no, why?
- If yes, theres another way to do it without *global member sharing*?

Comment: If you don't want them static, research member initializers.

Comment: ok thank you chris, but i tried the code, and the members are not being shared to all instances, how?? they are static..

Comment: They should be shared between all instances of the same template instantiation. Different instantiations of the template class are different types.

Comment: @Lucaswrk remember, `Matrix` instantiated with a different type for `T` or different numbers for `LIN` or `COL` will create a _completely separate and unrelated class_ that will have its own static members.

Comment: thank you @Seth, but why different numbers? you mean like instances with 5 for LIN and 8 COL will share between them? (considering the same type for T)

Comment: @Lucaswrk because `LIN` and `COL` are part of the template's parameters and determine how an actual class is created from the class template. A template is not a class, it is a mould for classes. So if you have `Matrix<int, 4, 4>` and `Matrix<int, 4, 5>`, they are different and unrelated classes and have separate static variables. The integral number parameters are the same as type parameters in this respect.

Comment: wow, now i got it, the template will create different class definitions for each T type and consts. Thank you so much @Seth Carnegie.